# R vector operation, insert value between the pattern

Tags: r, loops, matrix, vector

Suppose I have a vector like this :

```
 [1]  0  1  0  0  0  0  0 -1  0  1  0  0 -1  0  0  1 -1
```

And I want to turn this vector like this:

```
[1]   0 100 100 100 100 100 100 100   0 101 101 101 101   0   0 102 102
```

which just insert a value between [1,-1], and increase with the index.

How can I get this without using loop?

The original dataset can be produced by following code:

```
a = c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,1,0,0,-1,0,0,1,-1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(cumsum(a==1)+99)*
  `[<-`(numeric(length(a)),unlist(Map(`:`,which(a==1),which(a==-1))),1)
#[1]   0 100 100 100 100 100 100 100   0 101 101 101 101   0   0 102 102
```

Comment: Hi, nicola, It's cool ! But I can't understand all of it, could you explain more about the second part of your code, what is this `*
  `[<-`(numeric(length(a)),unlist(Map(`:`,which(a==1),which(a==-1))),1)` meaning?

Comment: double which craft

Comment: basically, `numeric(length(a))` creates a vector of 0s; `Map(":")` creates all sequences of successive indices, which are used to assign 1s at those positions (`[<-(x,i,1)` is `x[i] <- 1`). And the resulting boolean vector is used to filter the new values 99-102 obtained via `(cumsum(a==1)+99)`

Comment: Really clean code and cool method, I get it, thank you nicola !!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `which` to get the positions of values that are 1 and -1 in the `vector`, replicate the values 100:102 based on the corresponding length between the positions using `Map`, `rbind` it to create a `matrix`. and replace the positions in 'a' that corresponds to the first column position in 'm1' by the second column of 'm1'.

```
m1 <- do.call(rbind,Map(function(x,y,z)
       cbind(x:y,rep(z, y-x+1)), which(a==1), which(a==-1), 100:102))
a[m1[,1]] <- m1[,2]
a
#[1]   0 100 100 100 100 100 100 100   0 101 101 101 101   0   0 102 102
```

Comment: Thanks akrun, you help me a lot ! your explaination are really clear !

Answer (score 2):

I think this works,

```
tmp <- rle(cumsum(a) | a)
tmp$values[tmp$values] <- 99 + cumsum(tmp$values[tmp$values]) 
inverse.rle(tmp)
#  [1]   0 100 100 100 100 100 100 100   0 101 101 101 101   0   0 102 102
```

Comment: Thanks baptisite, I tried your method, It's worked ! But I still can't understand what is `rle` doing after I read about the help documents of it, could you explain more?

Comment: rle() encodes successive values that are identical by storing the list of values, and the indices where they change. Here I simply tweak those values before re-expanding the vector with the inverse operation.

Comment: Thanks again for your explaination, baptiste ! It's really a clean code :)